# Checking if a list is empty in java 8

Tags: filter, java-8, java-stream, empty-list

I am new to Java8.  I have implemented lists and filters.  I have done a null check in my code.  I would appreciate some help with how to check if the list is not empty in the same code snippet.  If the list is not empty then the code should proceed with the assertion.

```
    list.stream().filter(listElement -> listElement != null).
    forEach((listElement) -> Assert.assertEquals(
        ValueType.CANDY,
        listElement.getCandyType()));
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are asking an obsolete question. Streams process all elements of a source, hence, if there are no elements, no action will be taken. Therefore, you don’t need to check whether the list is empty.

Still, you can simplify your code:

```
list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(listElement -> listElement.getCandyType())
    .forEach(candyType -> Assert.assertEquals(ValueType.CANDY, candyType));
```

or

```
Assert.assertTrue(list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                      .map(listElement -> listElement.getCandyType())
                      .allMatch(Predicate.isEqual(ValueType.CANDY));
```

`allMatch` follows the rules required for this check. If there are no elements, there is no contradicting element, hence *all match*. Note that `listElement -> listElement.getCandyType()` also can be replaced by a method reference of the form `ClassName::getCandyType`; I didn’t do it here as I don’t know the correct class name.

There is no performance difference between both variants. `allMatch` will return immediately when encountering the first non-matching element, and `assertEquals` will throw on the first non matching element. In the second case, the stack trace won’t show artifacts of the stream API implementation.

The second one is preferred when you provide checks for production code rather than unit tests and allow to turn these checks off, as with the Java Language `assert` feature, e.g.

```
assert list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .map(listElement -> listElement.getCandyType())
           .allMatch(Predicate.isEqual(ValueType.CANDY));
```

as this form guarantees that there will be no overhead when assertions are turned off, whereas the first variant, having an `assert` statement with the `forEach` action may still cause iterating over all elements and performing the intermediate steps of the pipeline.

Comment: The disadvantage of your approach is that in case of failure the original code would display an actual non-matched value like "expected CANDY but was: SHMANDY" while your code would just say that assertion failed.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: my first variant still does that. Though it’s debatable whether that information really helps. Maybe the index would be more helpful, maybe the *other* nonmatching items, if there are some… Usually, the history that led to the erroneous state is what you need, but that’s something, neither variant can deliver.

Comment: Thanks.I selected your answer.It was very clear and improved on my code too.

Answer (score 28):

The chosen answer is great, just a small suggestion to handle null case with `Optional.ofNullable` of the [newly introduced to Java8 Optional class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_optional_class.htm):

```
  Optional.ofNullable(list)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
            .stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(listElement -> listElement.getCandyType())
            .forEach(candyType -> Assert.assertEquals(ValueType.CANDY, candyType)););
```

Answer (score 9):

Check out the `isEmpty` method

```
if (list.isEmpty()) { ... }
```

Here's the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to know the syntax of how it could be checked in the stream of Java8

Comment: If the list is empty, then the assert won't happen anyhow, since there won't be any elements for it to loop over

Answer (score 0):

Asserting that the list is empty is a separate thing from asserting that any particular element of the list has some form (i.e. `getCandyType() == ValueType.CANDY`). Trying to tie the two ideas together ever is just not the right way to do things.

What you need to do is to add a second assertion, either before or after the `forEach`, which does

```
assertThat(list.isEmpty(), not(equalTo(Boolean.FALSE)))
```

... or anything similar.

One of the major points about empty lists is that they can be processed in the same way as lists containing elements. This is why things like the [Optional class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) and the [Null pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) exist. So if you really care that the list is empty you really *should* make it a separate, distinct assertion.

Comment: If these utility methods do what their name suggest, `not(equalTo(Boolean.FALSE))` is quite an obfuscated way of saying `true`…

Comment: @Holger, I guess they also capable to format error message automatically (something like "it was not equal to FALSE"). Though such verbosity is absolutely unnecessary here.

Comment: @Holger you're right, the best assertion would probably use the hamcrest `IsEmptyCollection.empty()` matcher - `assertThat(list, not(empty()))`.